# WEBSITE Button that displays a random value from an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/7118zcfc

```
$scope.ctx.skills = data.result.skills;
    $scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn = [
    "Hooray",
    "Amount of mushrooms in Mario.", 
    "How to complete life.", 
    "How to create an aryan race",  
    "How paper papers", 
    "Do do do dododooooooo", 
    "A Level Physics / things you dont know = this site",
    "How to eat 200000 bananas in .23 seconds",
    "Why Jeremy Clarkson has curly hair.",
    "Starting to run out of things here",
    "Why Oli Stratford looks like James May",
  ];

 $scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn = $scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn.length)];

}
```

How do I make it so when the button that is shown on the jsfiddle is clicked one of these statements is put onto the web page in the same font.

Comment: You dint include angular inside your fiddle

Comment: also you dint connect it to the controller or the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on here that you'll need to fix. First, it looks like you're using Angular but its not included on the file. If you were going the Angular route you would have something that looks like:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button ng-click="getThingToLearn()" type="button">Learn Something</button>
<p>{{thingToLearn}}</p>

// JS
$scope.thingToLearn = '';
$scope.getThingToLearn = function () { 
    $scope.thingToLearn = $scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.ThingsYouWouldntLearn.length)];
}
```

If you're doing more of a JavaScript style then you could do something like:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button onclick="getThingToLearn()" type="button">Learn Something</button>
<p id="thingToLearn"></p>

// JS
var getThingToLearn = function () { 
    var thingToLearn = document.getElementById('thingToLearn');
    thingToLearn.textContent = ThingsYouWouldntLearn[Math.floor(Math.random()...
};
```

Hopefully this will help get you in the right direction to start fixing up your code.